# In CDK testing, what is the difference between toHaveResource and toHaveResourceLike?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, aws-cdk

In [CDK fine-grained construct tests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/testing.html), what is the different between

```
expect(...).toHaveResource(...)
```

and

```
expect(...).toHaveResourceLike(...)
```

from the `@aws-cdk/assert/jest` module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the code [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/ce9ee507caf9e4524c52c26a8cd3f255e6921e15/packages/%40aws-cdk/assert/jest.ts#L73) and [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/ce9ee507caf9e4524c52c26a8cd3f255e6921e15/packages/%40aws-cdk/assert/lib/assertions/have-resource.ts#L23) the only difference is that `toHaveResource` requires that values for the keys passed must match exactly, while in `toHaveResourceLike` actual values can be a superset of reference values. In other words, if you are trying to assert value of some property, which itself is an object, and you want to assert only subset of the object, then you should use `toHaveResourceLike`.

For example, let's say that you're trying to assert that your S3 bucket resource has a `PublicAccessBlockConfiguration` property with `BlockPublicPolicy` set to true.

You might write something like this:

```
test("has public access restricted", () => {
  expect(stack).toHaveResource("AWS::S3::Bucket", {
    PublicAccessBlockConfiguration: {
      BlockPublicPolicy: true,
    },
  });
});
```

But this will fail because `PublicAccessBlockConfiguration` also has other subproperties like `BlockPublicAcls`. But if you switch `toHaveResource` here to `toHaveResourceLike` then it will succeed.